# Finding PDF and CDF of the difference of two normal distributions that are not jointly normal

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, bivariate

Consider two standard normal random variables $X$ and $Y$ with density functions $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ and

$$p(x,y) = \begin{cases}
2p(x)p(y), & \text{if}~ x \geq 0, y \geq 0, \text{or}~ x < 0, y < 0,\\
0,& \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$

How do you go about finding the CDF and PDF of $Z = X - Y$

Comment: This reads a lot like a homework question. If it is, perhaps you would learn more from working it out yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the *question* asked: How do you go about finding the
CDF and PDF of $Z = X-Y$?:

I go about it as follows. I recall that for *any* pair of jointly continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$ (which in this instance $X$ and $Y$ *are*), the pdf of $Z = X-Y$ is given by

$$p_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty p_{X,Y}(x,x-z)\, \mathrm dx$$

and the cdf by

$$P_Z(a) = \int_{-\infty}^a \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty p_{X,Y}(x,x-z)\, \mathrm dx\right] \, \mathrm dz$$

and evaluate the integrals to find the pdf and the cdf.